# Multiple databases with one Fortrabbit app using Laravel 4.1 and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, fortrabbit

I'd like to be able to use multiple mysql databases in one Laravel app hosted on Fortrabbit - So I could make a sort of separate app in another page using a separate mysql database than the main app's mysql database. Is this an option with Fortrabbit's setup - or would I be better off making a whole new app and just make the separate app in a sub-domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortrabbit provides only one MySQL database per App. You can however access (your) other App's databases from any other App. Apart from this you could either get your own RDS instances on AWS and access them or use a third party vendor which offers (MySQL) databases.